# How to print multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have data from my shop in three arrays. The output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [infos] => Array ( [id_category] => 1...
```

I want to get `id_category`. Should I use two `foreach` or something else?

Comment: Do any of the outer arrays actually have more than one element? You'll need to use loops for any that do, but if not then you can just access it directly - `$array[0][1]['infos']['id_category']`

Comment: Have you tried the "two foreach "??

Comment: Does the `[1]` change? IE. Is an array of `[3][2]['infos']['id_category']` possible? Or will it always be like `[3][1]['infos']['id_category']`

Comment: Is anyone could check my file [link]https://ufile.io/9f8md and tell me is first array change ex [0][1] to [1][1] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example for using a **foreach**:

```
foreach ($array as $key1 => $level1){
    foreach ($level1 as $key2 => $level2){
        echo $level2['infos']['id_category'];
    }
}
```

Comment: if i have 3rd array inside 2nd array, then i need to use 3 foreach ?